# Correct unescaped text in HTML

Tags: java, string, docx4j

My question is not a duplicated question of the question presented above...

I have this text (from database) :

```
<p>I love Java & .NET ! <strong>5 > 3</strong></p>
```

As you see, the `&` and `>` is NOT escaped.

In Java, is there a way to turn this string into :

```
<p>I love Java &amp; .NET ! <strong>5 &gt; 3</strong></p>
```

As you noticed, **I want to keep all the HTML tags in same way they are**, but I want to escape the text, unvalid for XML (This text must be valid for Docx4J XHTMLImporter).

Thank you !

Comment: @Javad Your dup target is about escaping a whole string. This question is about escaping single characters, but leave the tags as is.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape characters to solve your problem.
For & sign you can use:
 `&#38;`
And for > you can use:
 `&#62;`
Full list of escape characters could be found [here](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php).

Comment: What about my HTML tag ? I really need the second string, not anything else !

Answer (score 0):

I used Jsoup and its parse function to clean my string :

```
    String unscappedHtml = " ";
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(unscappedText)) {
        // We remove width and height from image tags.
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(unscappedText);
        doc.outputSettings().syntax(Document.OutputSettings.Syntax.xml);
        doc.select("a").unwrap();
        unscappedHtml = doc.body().html();
    }
```